# Multiple numbers from one string

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr, stringi

I have the following value (and similar formatting in hundreds of thousands of fields):

```
61.00.62.1
```

that I would like to use a `stringr` or `stringi` and (likely) a regex to turn into

```
61.0
0.6
2.1
```

I have been unsuccessfully using the `stringi::stri_split_regex` command of the form

```
"[0-9]\\d{1,2}(\\.[0-9]\\d{1})"
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need to add some more detail. Will it always be just 2 digits between periods? If not, what about, for example, `61.1.62` or `61.025.6`? Where would you split those?

Comment: With your example (`x<-"61.00.62.1"`), something like `strsplit(x,"(?<=\\.[0-9])",perl=TRUE)` works. However, as @EdCottrell pointed out, you should define better how the split are obtained.

Answer (score 0):

I would try `stri_extract_all_regex`:

```
stringi::stri_extract_all_regex('61.00.62.1', '\\d{1,2}\\.\\d')
# [[1]]
# [1] "61.0" "0.6"  "2.1"
```

`\\d{1,2}\\.\\d` will match 1 to 2 digits followed by one point and one digit.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `strsplit`

```
strsplit(str1, "(?<=\\..)", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "61.0" "0.6"  "2.1"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "61.00.62.1"
```

Answer (score -2):

Make list of given string and separate list by each character by checking '.'